# ¿Cómo puedo pasar todos mis números obtenidos a una sola lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una función con la que obtengo números al azar o listas de números al azar para luego evaluarlos uno por uno. El problema es que al tener una lista dentro de una lista + algún numero cualquiera, por ejemplo:

```
lista_de_numeros = [[1, 2], 3, 4]
```

No puedo realizar operaciones como:

```
sum(lista_de_numeros)
>>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

¿Existe alguna manera de convertir **'lista_de_numeros'** a una lista de este tipo?:

```
lista_de_numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es con un sencillo ciclo `for` podemos hacer eso.

```py
lista_numeros2=[] #aquí se almacena el resultado
for i in lista_numeros:
    if type(i) is list: #si es un elemento de tipo list
        lista_numeros2 += i #agregamos la lista
    else: lista_numeros2.append(i) #agregamos el elemento

print(lista_numeros2)
```

Aquí estamos usando una propiedad de las listas donde si sumamos 2 listas (`[0,2]+[3,4]`) el resultado es una sola lista con todos los elementos (`[0,2,3,4]`).

También puedes hacerlo *"sin la creación de otra lista"* (explícitamente).

```py
for i in lista_numeros.copy():
    if type(i) is list:
        lista_numeros += i
        lista_numeros.remove(i) #quitamos la lista

print(lista_numeros)
```